# How does the FB.ui decide whether to put the notification next to the app bookmark or as red text at the top?

Tags: javascript, facebook-graph-api

When I run this request:

```
 FB.ui({ method: 'apprequests', 
        title:'Tell your friends about this Goal!',
        data:'http://blah.com',
      message: 'I wants to share a goal on my list with you!'});
```

The notification is posted in the right hand sidebar on your facebook landing page. Whereas, sometimes it will show the notification up top in red. Does anyone know what is required to get the notification to show up top in the notification jewel?

Quoting facebook**:
"In some cases of requests that Facebook predicts to be very relevant based on the recipients usage and relationship to the sender, the recipient may be made aware using a notification jewel."
** https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/

Referencing dialogs: https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/464/